# onEdit script not working I have changed it several times to find the problem

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I was getting an error that it could not find the source. I changed the script and fixed that, but now I get the following error:

> ( TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')

What am I doing wrong?
Here is my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  addTimeStamp(e);
  senEmail(e);
  
}


function addTimeStamp(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet5") ;
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var cellValue = range.getValue();


  if (col == 9 && cellValue === true){
    sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(new Date());
  }
}


function senEmail(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet5") ;
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('Sheet5');
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  let cellValue = range.getValue(); // The value of the edited cell

  // Check if the edit occurred in column 5 and the value is true
  if (col == 9 && cellValue === true) {
  
  let email = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  let name = sheet.getRange(row, 2);
  let orderID = sheet.getRange(row, 5);
  let orderDate =sheet.getRange(row, 1);
  let methodOfPayment = sheet.getRagne(row, 4);
  let numberOfTickets = sheet.getRagne(row, 6);
  let payableTotal = sheet.getRange(row, 7);
  let html_link ="https://checkout.payableplugins.com/order/"+[row,5];


  const subject = "PHLL Raffle Fundraiser Follow-Up on Order ID #" +row[5];
  const messageBody = 'Dear' + name + ',' + "\n\n" + 'We hope this message finds you well. We wanted to remind you that we have received your order information for the raffle ticket. According to our records, you have selected the cash method for payment, but we have not yet received the payment.' + "\n\n" + 'If you have already provided the payment to the player, please let us know as soon as possible. This will allow us to coordinate with them to ensure that your payment is collected and your raffle ticket is processed accordingly.' + "\n\n" + 'However, if you have not yet provided the payment to the player, we kindly ask you to do so at your earliest convenience. Once the payment is received, we will promptly send you your raffle ticket.' + "\n\n" +
'Please note that if payment is not received within the specified timeframe, we will have to remove your name from the drawing.' + "\n\n" +  'If you wish to change your method of payment, you may do so by following this link:' + html_link +   + "\n\n" + 'Should you have any further questions or concerns, please do not hesitate to reach out to us. We are here to assist you in any way we can.' + "\n\n" +  'Best of luck in the raffle drawing!'  + "\n\n" + 'Warm regards,'
const messageBody2 = 'ORDER DETAILS:' + "\n\n" + 'ORDER DATE:' + orderDate +"\n\n" + 'ORDER ID #' + orderID +"\n\n" + 'METHOD OF PAYMENT:' + methodOfPayment + "\n\n" + 'NUMBER OF TICKETS:' + numberOfTickets +"\n\n" +'PAYABLE TOTAL:' + payableTotal
const respondent = 'Treasurer' + "\n\n" + 'EmailAddress'   + "\n\n" + 'Paradise Hills Little League'

MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,messageBody,messageBody2,respondent);

console.log(sendEmail)

}
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  In which function does the error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a number of issues here:  First, range in line 25 is calling a sheet, not a range of cells.  I have changed it to `e.range` to call on the event object.

Also, I believe you have to use an installable onEdit trigger to utilize the mail service.  I changed the name of your function from `onEdit` to `onMyEdit` and set up an onEdit trigger.

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

[image: Screenshot3]

Second there are some misspellings:

First, `senEmail()` in line 4 and line 23.  Doesn't matter if you don't call that function but you do in the last line of your code.

Second, `getRagne()` in line 37 and line 38.

Additionally, I got the following error after these corrections had been made:

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,String,String) don't
> match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail.

I combined messageBody, messageBody2, and respondent to bring it in line with the method signature.

Lines 34 through Lines 39 need to have `getValue()` to get the cell values displayed in your HTML.

Finally, you have name and email calling on the same cell.  I changed the name to Column 3, but if this assumption is incorrect it can easily be modified.

These changes are reflected in the code below:

```
 function onMyEdit(e) {

  addTimeStamp(e);
  sendEmail(e);
  
}


function addTimeStamp(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet5") ;
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var cellValue = range.getValue();


  if (col == 9 && cellValue === true){
    sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(new Date());
  }
}


    function sendEmail(e){
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet5") ;
      var range = e.range;
      var row = range.getRow();
      var col = range.getColumn();
      let cellValue = range.getValue(); // The value of the edited cell
    
      // Check if the edit occurred in column 5 and the value is true
      if (col == 9 && cellValue === true) {
      
      let email = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
      let name = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
      let orderID = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
      let orderDate =sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
      let methodOfPayment = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
      let numberOfTickets = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
      let payableTotal = sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValue();
      let html_link ="https://checkout.payableplugins.com/order/"+orderID;
    
    
      const subject = "PHLL Raffle Fundraiser Follow-Up on Order ID #" + orderID ;
      const messageBody = 'Dear ' + name + ',' + "\n\n" + 'We hope this message finds you well. We wanted to remind you that we have received your order information for the raffle ticket. According to our records, you have selected the cash method for payment, but we have not yet received the payment.' + "\n\n" + 'If you have already provided the payment to the player, please let us know as soon as possible. This will allow us to coordinate with them to ensure that your payment is collected and your raffle ticket is processed accordingly.' + "\n\n" + 'However, if you have not yet provided the payment to the player, we kindly ask you to do so at your earliest convenience. Once the payment is received, we will promptly send you your raffle ticket.' + "\n\n" +
    'Please note that if payment is not received within the specified timeframe, we will have to remove your name from the drawing.' + "\n\n" +  'If you wish to change your method of payment, you may do so by following this link: ' + html_link + ' Should you have any further questions or concerns, please do not hesitate to reach out to us. We are here to assist you in any way we can.' + "\n\n" +  'Best of luck in the raffle drawing!'  + "\n\n" + 'Warm regards,' + "\n" + 'Treasurer,' + "\n" + 'EmailAddress'   + "\n" + 'Paradise Hills Little League' + "\n\n" + 'ORDER DETAILS' + "\n\n" + 'ORDER DATE: ' + orderDate +"\n" + 'ORDER ID #' + orderID +"\n" + 'METHOD OF PAYMENT: ' + methodOfPayment + "\n" + 'NUMBER OF TICKETS: ' + numberOfTickets +"\n" +'PAYABLE TOTAL: ' + payableTotal;
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,messageBody);
    
    console.log(sendEmail)
    
    }
    }
```

Note: you cannot run this code from the script editor.  There needs to be an event object for the script to run.  You will need to test it from the spreadsheet itself.

**Update**

Due to the structure of the code, I believe, sometimes multiple emails are being sent.  Below, I have restructured the code to remedy this and make it more efficient:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet5");
  var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var cellValue = range.getValue();
  let email = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  let name = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  let orderID = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  let orderDate =sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  let methodOfPayment = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
  let numberOfTickets = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  let payableTotal = sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValue();
  let html_link ="https://checkout.payableplugins.com/order/"+orderID;
  const subject = "PHLL Raffle Fundraiser Follow-Up on Order ID #" + orderID ;
  const messageBody = 'Dear ' + name + ',' + "\n\n" + 'We hope this message finds you well. We wanted to remind you that we have received your order information for the raffle ticket. According to our records, you have selected the cash method for payment, but we have not yet received the payment.' + "\n\n" + 'If you have already provided the payment to the player, please let us know as soon as possible. This will allow us to coordinate with them to ensure that your payment is collected and your raffle ticket is processed accordingly.' + "\n\n" + 'However, if you have not yet provided the payment to the player, we kindly ask you to do so at your earliest convenience. Once the payment is received, we will promptly send you your raffle ticket.' + "\n\n" +
'Please note that if payment is not received within the specified timeframe, we will have to remove your name from the drawing.' + "\n\n" +  'If you wish to change your method of payment, you may do so by following this link: ' + html_link + ' Should you have any further questions or concerns, please do not hesitate to reach out to us. We are here to assist you in any way we can.' + "\n\n" +  'Best of luck in the raffle drawing!'  + "\n\n" + 'Warm regards,' + "\n" + 'Treasurer,' + "\n" + 'EmailAddress'   + "\n" + 'Paradise Hills Little League' + "\n\n" + 'ORDER DETAILS' + "\n\n" + 'ORDER DATE: ' + orderDate +"\n" + 'ORDER ID #' + orderID +"\n" + 'METHOD OF PAYMENT: ' + methodOfPayment + "\n" + 'NUMBER OF TICKETS: ' + numberOfTickets +"\n" +'PAYABLE TOTAL: $' + payableTotal;
  
  if (editedSheet.getName() === "Sheet5" && col == 9 && cellValue === true){
  
  sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(new Date());
  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,messageBody);
  console.log(sendEmail)

}
}
```

Sample Email

[image: Screenshot4]

If this is not working for you or you have any further questions, let me know.

Comment: I cant thank you enough!!!! This has fixed my problem to exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you for the quick response and assistance

Comment: Glad I could help.  Check my update as well.  Sometimes I was getting two emails, so I restructured the code a bit.  Seems to have resolved that issue.